# need to find start and end time of events which is still not active

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, time-series

I have a table with 3 coulmne timestamp eventid active

| timestamp | eventid | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 22:44:23 | E1 | true |
| 2020-02-01 22:45:23 | E1 | false |
| 2020-02-01 22:46:23 | E1 | true |
| 2020-02-01 22:47:23 | E1 | false |
| 2020-02-01 22:44:23 | E2 | true |
| 2020-02-01 22:45:23 | E2 | false |
| 2020-02-01 22:46:23 | E2 | true |

need to find start and end time of events
here event e2 wont be considered as it is still active.

| Start_Time | End_Time | eventid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 22:44:23 | 2020-02-01 22:47:23 | E1 |

Update:
Able to find the solution using Pyspark see my answer below

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: @ Grdon updated the question, Regarding data base i am working on spark sql but any general sql(any database) would work

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select eventid, min(timestamp) as starttime, max(timestamp) as endtime
from t
group by eventid
having max(case when active = 'true' then timestamp else 0 end) = max(timestamp);
```

This returns events which are active on the most recent timestamp.

Comment: @Grondon, Thanks for the anwer but taking sum of timestamp wont help I guess

Comment: @MakeitEasy . . . That should be `max()` not `sum()`.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eventid ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rn
   FROM yourTable
)
SELECT min(yt.timestamp) as Start_Time, max(yt.timestamp) as End_Time,yt.eventid
FROM yourTable yt
inner join cte
On cte.eventid=yt.eventid
WHERE 
cte.rn = 1 and cte.active="false"
group by yt.eventid
```

In this way you will not see E2, because of it is still active.

Comment: How is it possible max(timestamp) to return false?

Comment: timestamp's data type is not boolean. So max(timestamp) will return a timestamp and not true or false.

Comment: I am not sure If i followed it completely but  as of my understanding "cte.rn = 1 and cte.active="false"" will elemenate everything i guess. so not sure

Comment: you can try, it will be what do you want. when cte.rn=1 and cte.active ="false" means that closed. So only "not active" result will be join with other table.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lead function I was able to find events which are complete.

```
window = Window.partitionBy('eventid').orderBy('timestamp')
eventWithLead = dataFrame.withColumn('endtime',lead(col('timestamp'), 1).over(window))\
                         .withColumn('nextstatus',lead(col('active'), 1).over(window))\
                         .select('eventid', 'active','endtime', 'timestamp', 'nextstatus')
   
openEvents = eventWithLead.select('eventId').filter(col('active')==True)\
                                            .filter(col('nextstatus').isNull())

errorWithLeadFinal = eventWithLead\
                         .join(openEvents, on=['eventid'], how='left_anti')
                         .filter(col('active')!= False)
                         .filter(col('nextstatus')!= True)
```